# If else statement in vb

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I have a button and i want it to check for a condition to display different msgbox.

Below is my code:

```
 Dim a As String = "";

Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If ((a = "a") & (DetailsSelectedComment.Visible = True)) Then
        MsgBox("Have")
    Else
        MsgBox("No have")
    End If

End Sub
```

But i got the following error when i clicked on the button.

"Input string was not in a correct format. "

Comment: This is precisely why you should make sure that Option Strict On is set either in your project properties or at the top of each code file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First remove the `";"` from your code while declaring the variable `"a"`
`Dim a As String = "";`  to `Dim a As String = ""`

And for making **and** operations in VB.Net we should use [AND](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sdbcfyzh%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) and ANDALSO

Answer (score 1):

I'm no VB expert - but I think it's because of

```
If ((a = "a") & (DetailsSelectedComment.Visible = True))
```

Replace the `&` with `And`.

See [& Operator in VB](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wfx50zyk%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) - it's a string concatenation operator - not a boolean operation.

Comment: Thanks.. It works.. I have messed up with all the syntax for different programming language..

Comment: easily done - as a C# developer, whenever I have to write VB I start to feel like I can no longer type!

Answer (score 0):

You should used `AND` operator. `&` is used for concatenation in VBnet.

```
Dim a As String = ""

Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If ((a = "a") AND (DetailsSelectedComment.Visible = True)) Then
        MsgBox("Have")
    Else
        MsgBox("No have")
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

1. The semicolon ";" in `Dim a As String = "";` needs to be removed.
2. `&` in VB.net is used for concatenation not as logical bitwise operator.

Change

`If ((a = "a") & (DetailsSelectedComment.Visible = True)) Then`

to

`If ((a = "a") And (DetailsSelectedComment.Visible = True)) Then`

Comment: Thanks.. It works.. I have messed up with all the syntax for different programming language..

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim a As String = ""

Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If ((a = "a") ANDALSO (DetailsSelectedComment.Visible = True)) Then
        MsgBox("Have")
    Else
        MsgBox("No have")
    End If
End Sub
```

the & operator is not a binary logical operator, just for string concatenation.
you can use AND or ANDALSO (ANDALSO will terminate the statement if the first condition is false, despite AND which will check the second condition if the first is false)

Answer (score 0):

There are several things wrong with your code, and unfortunately all the answers so far fail to mention at least one of those aspects.

1. Statements aren’t delimited by semicolon in VB.
2. `&` is the string concatenation operator. To test conjunctions, use `AndAlso`. To test disjunctions, use `OrElse`. In fact, even in C#, `&` would be wrong here since it’s the *bitwise and* but you want a logical conjunction which is `&&` in C#.
3. Do not compare a Boolean to literal `True` or `False`, that’s a meaningless operation. Just write / test the Boolean value directly.
4. Do not use redundant parentheses around your conditionals … overly nested parenthesised expressions make the code harder to read.
5. If you declare a variable at class level, use `Private` instead of `Dim`.
6. Always, **always** enable `Option Strict On` in your project settings.

Which leaves us with:

```
Private a As String = ""

Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If a = "a" AndAlso DetailsSelectedComment.Visible Then
        MsgBox("Have")
    Else
        MsgBox("No have")
    End If
End Sub
```